# Too Zoomed In On HDMI

Tags: display

After I sorted the RGB color issues, I found that even with overscan enabled, I was stupidly zoomed in. I had a look in `/boot/config.txt` but I am a novice and don't know what to edit.

Comment: What do you mean by too zoomed in?

Comment: I just needed to restart my Pi after having the HDMI connected and it auto-corrected.

Answer (score 2):

If by "zoomed in" you mean the resolution is too low, add:

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=16
```

And just comment out anything else to do with HDMI. This presumes you have a standard, 1080p HD display.  If not [see here for other options](https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/master/configuration/config-txt.md#hdmi_group).